# Active zone in a li

Tags: css, html-lists

I usually put display block to links to make all the div of a button active and not only the text. But in this case I need to use the `display:inline-block` in the `ul` `li` and I think this disable the other display block?. How to make all the `li` active and not only the text inside?

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/mPGDe/

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">first</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">second</a></li>
    <li><a href="#l">third</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    margin:40px auto;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    text-align: center;
}

ul li {
    position: relative;
    padding: 7px 17px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    display: inline-block; /* does it disable display block? */
}

ul li a {
    display:block;/* usually to make active all the zone, but here it does not work */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the paddings on the `a` instead of the `li`

```
ul li {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    display: inline-block; /* does it disable display block? */
}

ul li a {
    padding: 7px 17px;
    display:block;/* usually to make active all the zone, but here it does not work */
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/mPGDe/1/